# create hibernation partition on SSD (The drive cannot find the sector requested)

Tags: windows-8, partitioning, ssd, hard-drive-cache, zenbook

I try to create hibernation partition on SSD for expresscache purposes, but get error message "The drive cannot find the sector requested. See the System Event Log for more information." See the [information](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=63rtd3&s=6) about disk.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I send it to ASUS and they changed the Mainboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the specific error you are receiving but I'm pretty sure you can't move the location of the hibernation file. See The [File System Paradox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.11.windowsconfidential.aspx) by Raymond Chen for more information about why the hibernation file needs to be on the root of the c drive.

You don't provide info on whether this is a laptop or not but I am guessing by your reference to expresscache that it is. AFAIK the SSD used with expresscache is not available for partitioning or other use. The acceleration software has control of it for caching purposes.

Comment: I intend to create hibernation partition, but I'm not able to create partition at all.

Comment: Is this a laptop with expresscache? Does the SSD show up a normal drive?

Comment: Yes, it's laptop with expresscache (specifically Zenbook) and SSD is shown in Disk drives in Device Manager.